# Cannot access website

Tags: hosting

I have two ISP. The other one is hosting my website which is pcc.edu.ph. But when I try to access it from the other IP, it does not load the page it just says The connection was reset. But when I tried it from other IPs its loading ok. What could be the problem? Could it be a DNS or server problem? Im hosting it in ubuntu 12.04. I really need help!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you said two ISPs. How were you accessing the site ? from two different computers ? have you tried multiple computers with the bad ISP to confirm it's the problem with ISP and not just one particular computer ? To me this sounds like DNS issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply Serg. Yes the computers were connected form the two different ISPs. Yes I have tested it on multiple computers under that one ISP (which cannot access it). This ISP is Dynamic. I have also tested it outside and also asked my friends to access the site it works fine. Is there tweaking I need to do in my DNS? How? Im lost... :(

Comment: In that case you really should contact that isp. I doubt it's related to the ubuntu server itself

Comment: It worked with my isp all the way in Ukraine so it's only that isp that has issues

Comment: I already contacted the ISP. and they said they flushed the DNS and checked its still not accessible. For the server, I already whitelisted the dynamic IP (just for testing) and even reset the modem. But still no luck... If its a DNS issue, which i manage via Zoneedit. They have recently been acquired by easyDNS. Maybe it was with there transfer issues? anyway I appreciate your response serg. will be updating this thread for update. Thanks!!!

Comment: oh well any way it must really be an ISP issue :( :( :( been searching for solutions for months already...

Comment: This is my iptables policy: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination ACCEPT all -- 112.203.133.139 0.0.0.0/0 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination @Serg

Comment: Your website has an ip address,  right ? Can you try to ping the ip of the site while on a computer with bad isp ? Then try to ping by domain name. And let me know what happens in either case

Comment: Hi @Serg sorry for the late reply.. been busy this couple of days. i did wat u said and it was ok. i was pinging....

Comment: but the website is still not showing up..

Answer (score 0):

A "connection reset" error is a problem between the client and the webserver - it's the webserver sending the "connection reset", which means all of the DNS lookups have already occurred (successfully) before you even get to this stage.

If it was a DNS problem, you would be getting a "Server not found error", not connection reset. So whatever it is, it's on the server.

If there is nothing in the webserver config regarding these IPs, could there be some kind of iptables rule for the IPs the affected ISP is using? (iptables -L -n)

Comment: thank you for the reply sir markjr.. i'll try to look it up in the iptables... :-)

Comment: i have allowed the IP in iptables. but no luck :(

Comment: This is my iptables policy:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  112.203.133.139      0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination